# Can I use SCP to download data from Clickhouse server to my local workstation?

Tags: database, scp, clickhouse, mremoteng

I am trying to dump a CSV file for analytical purposes from Clickhouse. Currently, the dump occurs on the Clickhouse VM and I am unable to access it. Is it possible to use SCP to dump the data to my local machine instead of the server?

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22138783/303298

Answer (score 1):

CH HTTP API allows to get a query result in CSV format

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/http/

```
echo "select number, 'x' x from numbers(10) format CSV" | \
curl 'http://user:password@ch-host:8123/?query=' --data-binary @-
```