# Is it possible to copy files from local windows directory to remote linux directory?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scp

I am using ssh on a remote linux machine from my desktop using putty. I want to copy a txt file which is in the desktop of my local windows machine to the remote linux directory. How can i do that using shell when i am logged in to remote machine using ssh? Thanks for the help!

Comment: PSCP, the PuTTY Secure Copy client, is a tool for transferring files securely between computers using an SSH connection -- http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492023/transfer-files-command

Comment: I would suggest you use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) when you copy from your local Windows to a remote linux directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it can be possible, but you need additional software for that. Both [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) or [Git](https://git-scm.com/) bash will work. Since I use git as [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), I also use it to send files from my Window 7 laptop to remote AWS Linux machine.

Example login:

```
ssh -i key.pem user-name@public-dns **or** ip-address
```

To send a file from Window to remote (like AWS ec2):

```
scp -i key.pem file.txt user-name@public-dns:~/
```

To send a directory from Window to remote:

```
scp -i key.pem -r directory_name user-name@public-dns:~/
```

To receive a file from remote to Window:

```
scp -i key.pem user-name@public-dns:/file-address/file.txt any_name.txt
```

To recieve a directory from remote to Window:

```
scp -i key.pem -r user-name@public-dns:/directory-address/directory any_name
```

Comment: What's the key.pem?

Answer (score 1):

Open Git Bash and go into the location where the file to be copied then execute below the line in Gat Bash

```
scp -r user_name@<ip_address>:/<file_location> .
```

Example:

```
scp -r root@10.1.192.11:/piyush/upadhyay/sofcon_data .
```

Answer (score 1):

Open git bash, navigate to the folder, and execute the below commands.

```
ssh -i key.pem user@ip

scp -i key.pem your-files user@ip
```