# How to copy file from linux to windows

Tags: unix

Anyone please help me how to copy files from Linux command prompt to windows. I am connecting to Linux system using putty in windows system

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492023/transfer-files-command

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before you can start your transfer you should be following the below steps:

1. Setup your Linux sever for SSH access.
2. Install Putty on Windows machine.
3. The Putty-GUI can be used to SSH-connect to your Linux Box, but for file- transfer, we just need one of the putty tools called **PSCP**
4. With Putty installed, set Putty's path so that PSCP can be called from DOS command line.
5. Putty is installed with default settings (in C-drive).If you install Putty in some other DIR, please modify the below commands accordingly.
6. Now on Windows DOS command prompt:
   a) set the path from Windows Dos command line(windows): 
   type this command: 
   set PATH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY
   b) check / verify if PSCP is working from DOS command prompt:
   type this command:
   pscp

The copy command should be something like below:

```
pscp.exe linux-username@linux-server-ipaddress: [source-DIR-inLinux] [destination-DIR-inWin]
```

This [link](http://www.nairabytes.net/index.php/blog/62-geek/297-how-to-transfer-files-between-linux-and-windows-using-putty) should help...!

Comment: Remove the space in between the source-Dir and ipadress in order to avoid a "More than one remote source not supported" error

Comment: this is the format that worked for me `pscp.exe -P 22 linux-username@linux-server-ipaddress:[source-DIR-inLinux] [destination-DIR-inWin]` had to remove the space after `ipaddress:` and also add `-P 22` to solve `ssh_init: Network error: Cannot assign requested address` error