# ssh_init: Network error: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: deployment, putty, file-transfer

I am trying to set up a connection and transfer files using putty on a windows 10 platform.  I have verified that the default port in putty is 22.  When I run the command in the command line to connect and transfer files though I get the above error.  Any idea why this is or what I should do?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Did you try:

```
pscp -P 22 c:\documents\foo.txt user@example.com:/tmp/foo
```

Comment: why does the port have to be explicitly defined?

Comment: @mlhDev, when running `pscp` with `-v` (verbose), it prints `Connecting to example.com port 0`. So, it seems like default port for pscp is 0, not 22, which is weird.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/pscp-port-0.html) on clean machines and it has two workarounds. The answer by TomRod gives the preferable one-time permanent solution.

Comment: Worked for me. Although I was hoping it would 22 as it's default port.

Comment: I used -p (small) which is for preserved file attributes.It should be -P (capital) which is for port. to check all options, type pscp in command prompt.

Answer (score 22):

I had to go into the Putty Default Settings and "Save" them again, despite port 22 showing as the default. Worked for me to avoid adding the `-P 22` option every time.

Comment: This was it for me too. Not sure what it takes to get into that state, but for me it was on a pretty new install. The "Default Settings" saved session in putty showed port 22, and reloading kept port 22. But sure enough, saving it again made pscp start using port 22 for every IP I gave it, instead of the port 0 it had been using for every IP. Bizarre

Comment: This should be the accepted solution as it is a one-time fix. The answer should specify **Putty** Default Settings since they also affect the distinct pscp.exe tool.

Comment: For me, both `-P 22` and **saving** the Putty's Default Settings again worked but I would prefer Default Settings. Thanks @Martha

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and ended up at this page.  The `-P 22` did not solve my problem.

I use Putty saved sessions and double checked my command line and had the same error as the OP.

I was using:

`pscp -l SESSION_NAME_IN_PUTTY ip:/remote_path local_path`

I reviewed the [command line options](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage) for pscp and changed the `-l` to `-load` and it worked.

The final command looked like:

`pscp -load SESSION_NAME_IN_PUTTY ip:/remote_path local_path`

**Note**: If you still have the error, please review your spelling of  `SESSION_NAME_IN_PUTTY` and ensure it is an exact match.  One letter off, can cause the same error.

Comment: Also make sure you add `-r` if it's a directory you're pushing through `pscp`.

Comment: This was especially important for me, since my server requires MFA.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had created a shortened "session name" in Putty -- that is, a shorter representation of the full hostname.  This worked for most Putty functions -- but when I tried to use pscp I found that I needed to have a session name that was identical to the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I'm my case I was hitting this error because SSH was not enabled in Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add my comment to this since I spent ~ 3hrs trying to get it working and the fix was SIMPLE....

Trying to run this would give me the address error every time:

```
 putty -ssh 192.168.1.1 -P 22 -t -l root -i keyfile -m script.sh
```

After trying everything I could possible think of, one of the last attempts was rearranging the arguments and ended just being needing to move '-P' to AFTER '-t' and '-l':

```
 putty -ssh 192.168.1.1 -t -l root -i keyfile -P 22 -m script.sh
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).