# Using existing SSH session with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Imagine that you have a client and a server and that the client connects to the server using SSH (with or without Paramiko). Is it possible for Paramiko to utilize the already open SSH connection instead of creating a new one, so that another script can be ran on the server (and transfer a file back to the client for example) using the same existing connection? The goal is to avoid establishing multiple connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a programming/Python/Paramiko question. It's not possible with SSH at all. So it's not possible with Python/Paramiko either.

See

- [Transfer files to/from session I'm logged in with PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5492023/850848#28834936) or
- [Can you use SFTP to transfer files "backwards" to client during SSH on host?](https://superuser.com/q/1294788/213663#1294819)

---

Though if you connect with a (Python or whatever) script from the client machine, the remote script can talk to the local script to exchange the data (and the local script can save the data to a file).