# File transfer from hard disk to magnolia did not work

Tags: server, putty, file-transfer, magnolia

I am struggling to transfer a file from my hard disk to Magnolia server which is provided by my university. I have posted about the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087514/transferring-file-from-hard-disk-to-magnolia?noredirect=1#comment125667373_71087514). Someone suggest me to go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492023/transfer-files-to-from-session-im-logged-in-with-putty).

I add PuTTY in my path. Then I opened cmd and did the same thing as suggested on the above link. The file that I want to transfer to the magnolia cluster is a C file, named as mpi_hello.c. I have to transfer the the file inside csc510/mpi. csc510 folder is on the server and inside csc510 there is another folder mpi which is also in the magnolia server. I can show this two folder when I log in to the magnolia.

As the post suggested I typed `pscp mpi_hello.c@magnolia.universityname.edu:csc510/mpi/mpi_hello.c`

I got the result which shown below

[image]

Also nothing transferred to the csc510/mpi directory of magnolia cluster. How can I transfer the file from hard disk to magnolia server?

Thank you.

Comment: It's `pscp sourcefile<SPACE>username@host:destinationfile`

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my grade man. Thanks.