# Data upload using Putty from a Windows network to a remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, file-transfer, tunnel

I have some data files which are of the format `.tar.gz.partaa` on a Network, let's call it Network A . I can access it on my Windows network. I am using Putty to connect to a server B where I want to upload this data to a specific folder. How should this file transfer be done ?

I need this data to be transferred to the remote server B so that it can be further processed on Grafana and Influx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer files to/from session I'm logged in with PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492023/transfer-files-to-from-session-im-logged-in-with-putty)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not satisfy the answer. The solution mentioned here is not feasible due to the size of the data. The total data I have is approx 40 GB with each file around 2-3 GB. Additionally, the file type is .tar.gz.partaa. @TommasoVentafridda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching around on the internet, I found the following command which can be used to transfer the data to a server:

```
scp source_filename userid@server_name:/path_destination_filename
```

This tutorial can also be used as a reference: https://youtu.be/fmMg6cyww14